# Generate a ZMK Component only

Tags: cryptography, hsm

I have seen the command that generates and also *prints* the ZMK component. The command is : Generate and Print a ZMK Component for which the Command Code is 'OC'.

But I don't want it to be printed. But in 'OC' command it seems mandatory:

[image]

**Question:**
  Is there any way i can tweek this? Or any other command which just generates ZMK without the need to print it? I'm using *Thales HSM 9000*

Answer (score 0):

> from 1270A546-016 Host Command Reference v2.3b
> Notes:This command is superseded by host command 'A2'.
>   A printer must be attached to one of the USB ports on the payShield 9000. Serial-to-USB and parallel-to-USB cables are available from Thales, on request.

I believe that there is no way to use the Generate and Print a ZMK Component (OC) command without using a printer.

**Follow up**
Check the command Generate a Key (A0).
Mode  = 0 (Generate key)
 
Key Type = 000 (Zone Master Key,ZMK)

This is the A0 response using the Thales Test LMK 
HEADA100U6809C450D3F68AC78E80BA0C80E1D071F5EE20U6809C450D3F68AC78E80BA0C80E1D071F5EE20

Comment: Thanks You Panagiotis Giannakis! I will give it a try as i get access to HSM

Comment: Please let me know the results :)